# How to render optional text in string interpolation

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

I have this which works fine:

```
var firstName = "Greg";
var ipAddress = "0.0.0.0";

var sql = @$"sp_create_enrollment @first_name = '{firstName}',
        @ip_address = '{ipAddress}'";

Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

This produces:

`sp_create_enrollment @first_name = 'Greg', @ip_address = '0.0.0.0'`

However, if ip_address is null, I need it to produce this:

`sp_create_enrollment @first_name = 'Greg', @ip_address = null`

Note that there are no quotes around the null, otherwise it gets passed as a string.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: String interpolation isn't a template engine. It's not just the value that is optional here but how a missing value is handled (without quotes). To do this you need extra logic to create a quoted or unquoted string, resulting in extra allocations and more complex code. The answers aren't very readable.

Comment: Any particular reason *why* you are trying to do SQL injection? You should just use the normal `SqlCommand.Parameters` to properly parameterize your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var firstName = "Greg";
string ipAddress = "'0.0.0.0'";

var sql = @$"sp_create_enrollment @first_name = '{firstName}',
        @ip_address = {(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress) ? "null" : ipAddress)}";

Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

Comment: Putting everything in a single line results in code that's hard to read and hard to maintain. Especially in this case. Besides, a valid IP address will never have quotes, that's what the template should add

Answer (score 3):

```
ipAddress = ipAddress != null ? "'" + ipAddress + "'" : "null";

var sql = @$"sp_create_enrollment @first_name = '{firstName}',
        @ip_address = {ipAddress}";
```

Comment: This has quotes around the null : `sp_create_enrollment @first_name = 'Greg',
        @ip_address = 'null'`

Comment: @GregGum add quotes to `ipAddress` variable

Comment: Using `ipAddress` for both the original and modified value isn't a good idea. Debugging problems caused by eg bad input will be impossible. `var ip = ipAddress != null ? $"'{ipAddress}'" : "null";` is cleaner and avoids the allocations caused by string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

This is @Maytham's answer slightly modified:

```
var firstName = "Greg";
string ipAddress = null;

var sql = @$"sp_create_enrollment @first_name = '{firstName}',
        @ip_address = {(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress) ? "null" : "'" + ipAddress + "'")}";

Console.WriteLine(sql);
```

For creating SQL Passthrough, my preference is all one statement, but I wouldn't use it in other contexts.

Comment: Like most syntactic sugar functions, string interpolation can have great value. However, at the same time it's not one ring to rule them all. It can add readability and thus maintainability. I think this is an example of where good old string concatenation (or even a `StringBuilder` gives cleaner code than a complex one-liner/single statement (IMHO).

Comment: By the way, `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress) ? "null" : "'" + ipAddress + "'"` is quite confusing, as it leans on operator precedence: apparently the `+` concatenation has precedence over the `?:`.

Comment: That's not very readable and already at the limit of what can be maintained. What if you had to write somewhat more complex SQL?What if `ipAddress` had a bad value? What if you had to script multiple enrollments? Or add some error handling? How *quickly* can you modify, generate and test your script now? I had to generate a bunch of SQL scripts from metadata recently, includings tables, and things went a lot smoother and faster once I started using template engines like Jinja. [Scriban](https://github.com/scriban/scriban) uses an equivalent syntax in C#.

Comment: For example, `@"{{ for e in enrollments }}sp_create_enrollment @first_name = '{{- e.FirstName -}}', @ip_address = '{{- e.ipAddress -}}'
GO
{{end}}`. There's a `string.literal` that can double-quote an input, eg `{{- ipAddress | string.literal -}}`. For single quotes you could use `{{if e.IpAddress}} '{{e.ipAddress}}' {{ else }}null{{end}}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with an extension method (as suggested by @Panagiotis Kanavos):

```
var firstName = "Greg";
string ipAddress = null;

var sql = @$"sp_create_enrollment @first_name = {firstName.QuoteOrDefault()},
        @ip_address = {ipAddress.QuoteOrDefault()}";

Console.WriteLine(sql);

public static string QuoteOrDefault(this string value)
{
    if(value is null)
    {
        return "null";
    }
    else
    {
        return "'" + value + "'";
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing that needs to be extracted is that big `(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress) ?  ...` not the quote operation. A `QuoteOrDefault` method would make sense. It's also better to use a StringBuilder as every benefit of interpolation is lost now - the code is hard to read and generates a lot of temporary strings.

Comment: Love the QuoteOrDefault idea.  See my updated answer.